# AFNetworking response for "key": "\u0001" Not recieved

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, afnetworking

For my AFNetworking request I expect such "key": "\u0001" response but i am not getting rather I get "key": "". I tried following multiple stack questions but didn't work for me.

```
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:15];
manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObject:@"application/json"];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;
manager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = false;
[manger.requestSerializer setValue:@"Application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
manger.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];
[manger GET:url parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *operation, id responseObject){
        NSLog(@"Response REST AP loaded %@", responseObject);
        NSMutableDictionary *response = responseObject;
}
```

It worked in String format when i wrote this line of code

```
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

But now i don't know how to make it to NSDictionary, i also tried converting this to NSDictionary

```
NSData *webData = [newStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:&error];
```

This did not work.

Can anyone guide me proper steps how to achieve my expected output.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you should check responseObject type, for example:

```
          if ([[responseObject class] isSubclassOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) {
            // return responseObject because this is a dictionary
          }
          else {
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
            NSData *webData = [newStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
            return [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:webData options:0 error:&error];
          }
```

Comment: i am getting response as NSDictionary, my question

i am not getting this "key": "\u0001" insted i am getting this   "key": ""

Hope i am clear

Comment: Should you try to test response from Postman plugin of Chrome? If a dictionary is empty value, contact your backend.

Comment: This value is expected  "key": "\u0001" to come i have tested in postman too. It comes there but i am not receiving here via AFNetworking.

Comment: Please try AFHTTPRequestOperationManager instead of AFHTTPSessionManager:

Answer (score 0):

```
NSDictionary* responseDict = [self dataObject:responseData];
```

use this and then call this method

```
- (id) dataObject:(NSData*)data
{
    return [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];
}
```

Comment: I think this "\u0001" is code for special character in ios.

Comment: its unsigned character not special character

Answer (score 0):

Try another ways:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];

manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
[manager.requestSerializer setTimeoutInterval:15];
manager.securityPolicy.allowInvalidCertificates = true;
manager.securityPolicy.validatesDomainName = false;
manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:requestURL parameters:params success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"Response REST AP loaded %@", responseObject);
}
```

Comment: The problem is just in response, as when i use this 
NSString* newStr = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

I get proper response but its in string, and i need it in dictinary